# Facebook Page not showing in Mobile App. How to fix?

Tags: facebook

I manage a Facebook page that for some reason can't be accessed via the Facebook App (iPhone 11 Pro Max). I can find it via search, but upon clicking on the page, I get "Unable to load Page. Tap to Retry".

I can find and view the page just fine on the desktop version of Facebook, and there are no restrictions in place that limit the viewing of the page. The page has been active for over a year and is for a restaurant.

It appears to be working on Android devices, but not on iOS. I have tried with 3 different phones and get the same result. Myself and the other users I've tested this with are able to see other pages, just not this specific one.

I can't seem to find any articles elsewhere on the Internet regarding this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to Facebook.